# SVD of a parametrized matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose we have a parametrized matrix $Z(λ)\in R^{m\times n}$ where $λ\in(a,b)$ and $Ζ(λ)$ is an analytic function of $λ$, e.g. $Z(λ)=λA+(1-λ)B$ where $A,B \in R^{m\times n}$. In general, the (parametrized) SVD  of such matrices is given by **analytic SVD** algorithms, but the value of λ should be computed along with the elements of $U$, $Σ$ and $V^{Τ}$.

Starting from 
$λΑ+(1-λ)Β=UΣV^{T}$, we do the matrix multiplication to arrive to the system $λa_{ij}+(1-λ)b_{ij}=u_{ik}σ_kv_{jκ}$ where $i=1,...,m$, $j=1,...,n$ and $k=1,...,rank(Ζ(λ))$. Can I compute $λ$ as part of an SVD computation somehow?

Comment: Please, do an effort to help me, as my question is related with a crucial problem in my MSc research. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Do you beed to find a relationship like $\lambda=f(A,B, U, V, Sigma)$?

Comment: Maybe it's a good starting approach.

Comment: Are you actually trying to find SVD of $Z$ as a function of $\lambda, A, B$ (i.e. $U = f_U(\lambda, A, B)$, $\Sigma=f_{\Sigma}(\lambda, A, B), V=f_{V}(\lambda, A, B)$? If so, are there any constrains on $A$ and $B$ (i.e. Hermitian)? If there aren't any, I fear this problem leads to deep/unresolved waters.

Comment: I might be mistaken though

Comment: Hmm... we can safely consider that $A,B\in[0,1]^{m]times n}$. That's the only admissible constaint on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So in your problem what are the unknowns and what are the knowns? I guess $A,B$ are known. Then do you want to find $U,V,\Sigma$ as a function of $\lambda$ or the other way around?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay $A$ and $B$ are known. Using methods for analytic SVD computation, I can forms of $U$, $Σ$ and $V$ that are analytic functions of $λ$. I want to find $λ$ as a function of all these factors as a first step (see Upax's comment).

Comment: Oh, then you can find $\lambda$ from each of the equations you wrote right?

Comment: That should be obvious if we weren't know that for a paramatrized matrix $A(λ)$, its SVD factors $U$, $Σ$ and $V$ are also functions of $t$ (in other words, their elements are functions of $λ$ and NOT mere values).